# Sum the cells that are next to the cells that are not blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns.

Range c5:c40 (or c5:lastrow) contains the price.

range D5:D40 (or D5:lastrow) contains a date.

I want to sum the cells in 
c5:c40 (or c5:lastrow)

that are next to the cells in D5:D40 that contains the date.

I have the following code but this gives me only the value of True in cells D2:D3 instead of a number

```
.Range("D2:D3").Merge
.Range("D2:D3").Value = "=SUMIF(D5:D6," <> ",C5:C6)"
```

How can I get the sum?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid if I misunderstood you. May the following code help you?

```
Sub testing()
    Dim total As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 5 To 40
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 4)) Then
            total = total + Cells(i, 3)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```